# Error on starting maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a simple maven project and stumbled on an error upon executing this conmmand in the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I am using fresh out of the box maven so I still don't have a settings.xml. Maven says that I don't have the `archetype` plugin and upon looking for solutions I found out that the maven central repo is not accessible in my network(maybe configured in firewall). How can I proceed now?

Thanks

Comment: Tried using a proxy? http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: @GregKopff I could try doing your suggestion, could you give me an idea where could I find a proxy host?

Comment: Ask your network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have net access, try downloading the required artifacts and placing them in your local repository. The local repository path would be in the settings.xml file placed in your maven installation directory/conf. You can also try connecting to the maven central repository using a proxy setting if it is feasible.

Comment: hi sir, wouldn't downloading the required artifacts manually defy the purpose of maven?

Comment: Yes, it does. Maven requires access to a repository from where it can automatically resolve dependencies and fetch them, if they are not already present in your local repository. But in your case, the repository is not accessible. The ideal way would be to setup a proxy connection to the central maven repository which should also serve you in the future.

Comment: Okay i'll try your second suggestion. I've read about setting up a proxy in the settings.xml but could you suggest how can I find a host proxy?

Comment: Hi sir, I haven't talked to our net ads yet. Will keep you posted and update this question. Thanks.